# Function Limit in SQL is not working correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get the latest entry from users and I am using the following statement:

```
    SELECT [username]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Surname]
      ,[Email]
      ,[Phone]
      ,[Mobile]
,[Query]

  FROM [ECom].[dbo].[Queries]
  ORDER BY [ECom].[dbo].[Queries].[username] DESC LIMIT 1
```

I am getting the following error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.

PS: I am also trying it this way but the error keeps popping up:

```
 SELECT [username]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Surname]
      ,[Email]
      ,[Phone]
      ,[Mobile]
,[Query]

  FROM [ECom].[dbo].[Queries]
  ORDER BY [username] DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The code is sqlserver which has TOP rather than limit. (the error message is sqlserver too)

Answer (score 1):

Your error message indicates that you are running SQL Server, as does the use of square brackets around identifiers.

`limit` is not e thing in SQL Server. Instead, use `top`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) [username]
     ,[Name]
     ,[Surname]
     ,[Email]
     ,[Phone]
     ,[Mobile]
     ,[Query]
FROM [ECom].[dbo].[Queries]
ORDER BY [username] DESC
```

Starting SQL Server 2012, you can use a `fetch` clause, which is standard ANSI SQL  (although it is not implemented in MySQL...):

```
SELECT [username]
     ,[Name]
     ,[Surname]
     ,[Email]
     ,[Phone]
     ,[Mobile]
     ,[Query]
FROM [ECom].[dbo].[Queries]
ORDER BY [username] DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROW
```

If you want the last record of each user, then it is a different question. One option uses window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select q.*, row_number over(partition by username order by ?? desc) rn 
    from ecom.dbo.queries q
) q
where rn = 1
```

The `??` should be replaced with the name of the column that defines the ordering of the rows for each user.

You can also do this with `top` of `fetch` - but you need to put the window function in the `order by` clause:

```
select top (1) with ties q.*
from ecom.dbo.queries q
order by row_number over(partition by username order by ?? desc) rn
```

Comment: But this only shows me one record, I want to show the last record of each user

Comment: @Burdy: this was not clear at all in your original question... Which column should be used to order the records of each user?

Comment: I'm so sorry, the column that has to be used is the username, as I want to get the latest query from each username

Comment: @Burdy. The edited answer does that. You just need to choose the correct column to order the records, as explained already.